# Set in Typescript/ECMAScript characteristic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am now learning Typescript and have some problem understanding some section of document. Refer to the code on typescript.lang Handbook

```
let pets = new Set(["Cat", "Dog", "Hamster"]);
pets["species"] = "mammals";

for (let pet in pets) {
   console.log(pet); // "species"
}

for (let pet of pets) {
   console.log(pet); // "Cat", "Dog", "Hamster"
}
```

I do not understand why Set can be set with key like 'species' pets["species"] = "mammals". Set is not key-value characteristic by default I suppose?

and why for (let pet of pets)  is "Cat", "Dog", "Hamster" no "mammals"

Please help describe. Many thanks

Comment: That is not how you add a value to a set. It has a `.add` method to add values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set is an iterable object the initial array sets are the iterable values thats why you can access them through for..of. when you say `pets["species"]= "mamals"` you are creating a property "species" with a value of "mamals" but that is not part of the iterable values, thats why you can see it when using for..in.

for..of will display the values of an iterable while for..in will show the properties of an object. I hope this helps

Comment: when I say let pets = new Set(["Cat", "Dog", "Hamster"]); does that mean pets has an inferred type as Set, or it still be any object. When you say property "species", you mean property of object not Set, am I right? Many thanks for your great answer. And why for..in is just "mammal", why not index of Cat, Dog, Hamster which is 0, 1, 2. My reference is from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html

Comment: everything in JS exept literals is an object even functions, Sets are objects too. Set happens to have a set of non enumerable properties that help you manage it. for..in only access "species" because that is the property name and is enumerable so it will be listed by for..in